# HD clone using LZ4 and DD fails

Tags: dd, system-recovery

I've been cloning complete HDD images to restore OS crashes using DD and GZIP for a while now using `dd if=/dev/sda | gzip > img.gz` and `gzip img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda`

This always working fine, but the process is a little slow. It takes more than 2 hours to create or restore an image. I started experimenting with faster (de)compression; LZ4.

Again, using the same commands `dd if=/dev/sda | lz4 > img.lz4` and `lz4 img.lz4 | dd of=/dev/sda`. Creating and restoring an image now takes less than 50% of the time. Point is, this restored image delivers a unbootable PC.

What am I doing wrong? Is LZ4 not suitable for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the restored image the same size as the original one ?

You can test restored size using :

`lz4 -v img.lz4 > /dev/null`

If not, maybe the following line would be a bit safer :

`lz4 -d img.lz4 | dd of=/dev/sda`

Comment: You are right. Adding the -d argument helped. Although the man page says if the file extension is .lz4, it automatically adds the -d argument. Apparently this doesn't work when the output piped towards another application.